# Guidance for CDF Development, Security and Future of CDF?

Tags: security, cdfplayer, enterprise-cdf

We have a number of R&D projects where we would like to show on going results in a distributed CDF application. This would be similar to monthly reports.

There are some fairly heavy security requirements where we are contractually obligated to protect data. The data is proprietary - certainly not top secret.  However, the costs associated with a data breach would be significant.

These obligations prohibit us from using Cloud based systems or using web-based services. Internal data systems must meet some fairly stringent STIGs.  This is literally a case where we will hand deliver CDF content on a CD or DVD.

A few questions about CDF usage:

- Is it possible to warn the user that an Internet connection exists and terminate?
- Data must be secure - is it possible to make a call to a custom assembly from a CDF that handles decryption of data?
- Will there be a time in the next 10 years where CDF Player will require an Internet connection to work?
- Are there some books that do detailed treatments on CDF development?

Comment: Couldn't you get your data via secured company intranet? That way no data is in your CDF or saved in your CDF, in case it is obtained by someone outside your company.

Comment: Some reviewers do not have access to the company intranet. CDs are hand delivered - reviews are witnessed - CDs are not left with the reviewer.

Comment: What kind of custom assembly did you have in mind for calling data? If CDs are hand delivered, witnessed and retrieved is their any reason why the data cannot be stored on them (presumably CDs later destroyed?)

Comment: I had a .net assembly in mind - data will be on the CD but encrypted as a precaution.  CDs are destroyed afterwards - (and chain of custody updated and regularly audited).  The same assembly would handle authentication.  Pass key would be required to start the CDF. If someone found a CD they would not have access to unencrypted data.

Comment: Since you are physically present for the reviews, the best option is to do away with the CDs and bring a computer that has no network adaptor to the reviewer. For applications on the intranet I use CDFs that get all their data from a file server that we control and log access to. Loss of the CDF is not an issue because they contain no sensitive information.